# Displaying Foreign Key Referenced value Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, reference, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:
**musiccollection**: id (pk), title, artist.. etc etc
**musiccollection_playlist**: mcpid (pk), playlistid (fk:playlist.playlistid), trackid(fk:musiccollection.id)
**playlist**: playlistid (pk), playlistname

I want to display the whole rows in musiccollection as shown in the musiccollection_playlist table respective foreign key.

ex. in musiccollection table

```
id    title    artist 
1     song1    artist1
2     song2    artist2
3     song3    artist3
4     song4    artist4
5     song5    artist5
```

ex. in playlist table

```
playlistid    playlistname
1             playlist1
2             playlist2
```

ex. in musiccollection_playlist

```
mcpid    playlistid    trackid
1        1             2
2        1             4
3        1             5
```

Now I want to display the data in musiccollection_playlist WHERE playlistid is 1 (general example). However I want the returned data to be the actual rows in music_collection table where the id's chosen would be 2,4,5.

I am attempting to write the query:

```
SELECT * FROM musiccollection as a, musiccollection_playlist as b WHERE a.id IN (SELECT trackid FROM musiccollection_playlist) AND b.playlistid = '1'
```

I have to be reasoning something out wrongly or I have something wrong in the query.
How can I fix this to achieve what I want? i.e. display the whole row identified by the trackid in musiccollection_playlist.

In reality I can do something like:

```
SELECT trackid FROM musiccollection_playlist WHERE playlistid = '1'
```

The trackid then has to reference from the musiccollection table.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition:

```
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT trackid FROM musiccollection_playlist)
```

will only limit the results to every track which is in any playlist.

I think you need to review the documentation on [joins](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-WHERE). They can make life a lot simpler:

```
SELECT a.* FROM musiccollection a INNER JOIN musiccollection_playlist b ON
  a.id = b.trackid
WHERE b.playlistid = '1';
```